# What can we do to get the traffic up on the DIY Meta Community?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I put this as an answer to [this](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/520/4357).  Since I don't know what can and can't be done maybe all of this is verboten.  But I do feel strongly about getting more participation in our site.

My answer was maybe we could have a DIY Site Tip and offer tips on making questions better, how to look at the suggested box when asking questions, choosing correct tags, adding pictures, adding links, adding pictures if you are new to the site and other things that can be found in the faq or we can dream up.

I was hoping we could 'pin' it to be the first question in the meta site.  If not maybe we could make our own [Community Promotion Ads](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/community-promotion-ads-2012) featuring protected Community questions and answers that really point out problem areas, or at least the most repeated problems.

I feel the 1 or 2 questions or posts per week on this Meta site could be better.  I don't know if it would help the site or not but maybe it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Badges!

`Community Education` - Asked a question and accepted an answer on Meta.
`Concerned Citizen` - Visited Meta 30 consecutive days.
`Patriot` - Visited Meta 100 consecutive days.
`Volunteer` - Answer score of 10 or more on Meta.
`Pro bono` - Answer score of 25 or more on Meta.

I know badges can already be earned on Meta (but who cares about those), these badges would be earned on the main site for participating on Meta.